# How are unwanted coefficients eliminated in trig functions?

Tags: calculus, integration

I had to do this integral,I did it in a very hard way, but in the textbook it is evaluated very easily by changing the upper limit to $\pi$
$$\int_0^L x\sin^2(\frac{n\pi x}{a})$$
But I'm confused by the next step
$$=\int_0^L x\sin^2(\frac{\pi x}{a})$$
Where did n go? By the way it is given that n is an integer,or
$$\sin^2({n\pi})=0$$

Comment: Those two integrals are not equal for general $a,$ $L,$ and $n.$ But for some values it is true. Perhaps if you show the full context it will be clearer what the claim was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx= \int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) dx~~~~(1)$$
Now take $$I=\int_{0}^{L} x \sin^2 \left (\frac{2n\pi x}{a} \right) dx~~~(2)$$
Use (1) to get $$I=\int_{0}^{L} (L-x) \sin^2 \left (\frac{2n\pi (x-L)}{a} \right) dx$$
If $L=m a/2$, then
Then $$I=\int_{0}^{L} (L-x) \sin^2 \left (\frac{2n\pi x}{a} \right) dx~~~~~(3)$$
Adding (2) and (3), we get
$$2I=L\int_{0}^{L}  \sin^2 \left (\frac{2n\pi x}{a} \right) dx=(L/2)\int_{0}^{L} [1-\cos (4n\pi x/a)]~~~(4)$$
$$\implies I=\frac{L}{4} [x-\frac{a}{4n \pi}\sin (4n\pi x/a)]_{0}^{L}=\frac{L^2}{4},~~L=ma/2, m=1,2,3,...$$

In general, for  any $L$ the integration by parts yields:
$$I=\left|\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{a^2}{32n^2\pi^2} \cos(4n\pi x/a)-\frac{ax}{8n \pi} \sin(4n\pi x/a)\right|_{0}^{L}$$

Comment: I think you meant $L=ma$ before equation $(3)$. And in the end does it turn out that $L=(m+1/2)a$ also works? Or more simply, we can use $L=ka/2$ for any integer $k$?

Comment: @David K Thanks for pointing out this in fact $L=ma/2, m=1,2,3,...$ will give $I=L^2/4.$.